# Injecting multiple Services to Controller throws error- AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

My code is like this

```
Services.JS
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.services', []).factory('rateRequestService', ['$http', rateRequestService]);

function rateRequestService($http) {
    var service = { getData: getData};
    return service;
    function getData() {
        return $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: '../services/asas.asmx/GetReadOnlyData?shipmentID=' + getQuery('shipmentId')
        });
    }
    function getQuery(name) {
        var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
        return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
}

angular.module('RateRequestApp.services', []).factory('rePrintService', ['$http', rePrintService]);
function rePrintService($http) {
    var service = { getReprintData: getReprintData };
    return service;
    function getReprintData() {
        return $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: '../services/asas.asmx/RePrint?shipmentID=' + getQuery('shipmentId')
        });
    }
    function getQuery(name) {
        var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
        return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }

}


Controller.JS


    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller
('ReadOnlyController', [
    '$scope', 'rateRequestService', 'rePrintService', '$controller',
    function($scope, rateRequestService, rePrintService, $controller) {
        $scope.rateData = [];
        rateRequestService.getData().success(function(response) {
                $scope.rateData = response;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
        rePrintService.getReprintData().success(function(response) {
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});

    }
]);

App.js
angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
   'RateRequestApp.services',
   'RateRequestApp.controllers',
   'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

Everything looks okay to me, But this throws an error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: rateRequestServiceProvider <- rateRequestService
```

When I Inject only my first service, It works correct. but when second comes it breaks.
Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have two modules

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.services', [])
```

definitions, so the second one overwrites the first one which holds `rateRequestService` service.

To properly retrieve existent module you need to use getter syntax:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.services').factory('rePrintService', ['$http', rePrintService]);
```

Note that there is no dependency array `[]` after module name.

Or you can use chain notation like this:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.services', [])
.factory('rateRequestService', ['$http', rateRequestService])
.factory('rePrintService', ['$http', rePrintService]);
```

Comment: Can you add a solution here, where I can use both my services?

Comment: @Athul in your question above you just defined your two services and never used it, maybe you have to provide further information about your usage, i.e. your controller where you use your services.

Answer (score -2):

First thing that I am noticing is that the code itself needs to be better organized to be honest, but anyways.
Second thing is that you need to add the module that you created into your "RateRequestApp.controllers" module. So that the code entirely would be something like:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', ['RateRequestApp.services']).controller
```

This + the previous answer should do the trick.
good luck